# How to use TitanFactory.open()?

Tags: cassandra, titan

I'm new to Titan and now I'm trying to connect to database.

There is a server and in this server there is a titan graph.

I found some documentation:

- https://github.com/tinkerpop/blueprints/wiki/Batch-Implementation
- [How to import a CSV file into Titan graph database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19006616/how-to-import-a-csv-file-into-titan-graph-database)

And I'm trying to use the following code:

```
TitanGraph titanGraph = TitanFactory.open("I don't know what to write here");
BatchGraph bg = new BatchGraph(titanGraph, VertexIDType.STRING, 1000);
```

In this code block I'm not sure how to configure the `TitanFactory.open()` function. What should I put instead of the text `"I don't know what to write here"`?

Or are there any examples for connecting to a remote titan graph using `TitanFactory`? I've found some examples but they seem out of date (some class names and parameters are now different) so I'm unable to use them...

Comment: What version of Titan are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The official Titan documentation for Titan 0.5.4 is located here.
http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/docs/titan/0.5.4/

If you're new to Titan, you should start by going through it. Chapter 3 covers getting started with and features an example of how to use TitanFactory.open().
http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/docs/titan/0.5.4/getting-started.html#_loading_the_graph_of_the_gods_into_titan

The String parameter on TitanFactory.open() is the location of a properties file which configures the backend storage for the graph. There are several example properties files in the Titan [download](https://github.com/thinkaurelius/titan/wiki/Downloads) that you can try out.

Comment: Thanks Jason, i read my question and i figure out that i couldnt explain what i want exactly. I gave the location of properties file but it didnt work. I run the code on my local but titan works on remote linux machine. Can you please check my second question

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32519516/titanfactory-open-configration