# titan, loading data with batchgraph

Tags: graph, titan, bulk-load

I want to load 2.5 millions vertex into titan with client application. I have formatted txt file. First line of this file;

id:12345,companyname:Abcd,country:Abcd,... format(propertyname:propertyvalue,...)

I tried load sample 100 lines into titan using Rexter from my client app and succeed.

For 2.5 millions lines, i think using BatchGraph is the best way. For testing  just get first line and saved as test.txt

Successfully compiled and run this code;

```
            BaseConfiguration config = new BaseConfiguration();
            config.setProperty("storage.backend", "inmemory");
            config.setProperty("storage.hostname", "192.168.200.141");
            config.setProperty("storage.port", "8182");
            config.setProperty("storage.batch-loading", "true");
            TitanGraph graph = null;
            graph = TitanFactory.open(config);
            BatchGraph bg = new BatchGraph(graph, VertexIDType.NUMBER, 1000);
            Vertex currentNode = null;

            String path = "c:\\test.txt";
            Charset encoding = Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1");
            List<String> lines = null;
            try {
                lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(path), encoding);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            for (String line : lines) {
                currentNode = bg.addVertex(1);
                String[] values = line.split(",");
                for (String value : values) {
                    String[] property = value.split(":");
                    currentNode.setProperty(property[0].toString(), property[1].toString());
                }
                bg.commit();
            }
```

When adding property, getting this error;

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Property Key with given name does not exist: id
at com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.types.typemaker.DisableDefaultSchemaMaker.makePropertyKey(DisableDefaultSchemaMaker.java:27)
at com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.transaction.StandardTitanTx.getOrCreatePropertyKey(StandardTitanTx.java:902)
at com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.vertices.AbstractVertex.setProperty(AbstractVertex.java:239)
at com.tinkerpop.blueprints.util.wrappers.batch.BatchGraph$BatchVertex.setProperty(BatchGraph.java:492)
at tr.com.titanbulk.TitanBulk$5.widgetSelected(TitanBulk.java:213)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Unknown Source)
```

I have already set property keys and composite index via gremlin;

```
mgmt = g.getManagementSystem()
id = mgmt.makePropertyKey('id').dataType(Integer.class).make()
companyname = mgmt.makePropertyKey('companyname').dataType(String.class).make()
country = mgmt.makePropertyKey('country').dataType(String.class).make()
mgmt.buildIndex('ni_id',Vertex.class).addKey(id).buildCompositeIndex()         
mgmt.buildIndex('ni_companynamecountry',Vertex.class).addKey(companyname).addKey(country).buildCompositeIndex()
mgmt.buildIndex('ni_companyname',Vertex.class).addKey(companyname).buildCompositeIndex()
mgmt.buildIndex('ni_country',Vertex.class).addKey(country).buildCompositeIndex()
mgmt.commit()

g.getIndexedKeys(Vertex.class)
==>id
==>companyname
==>country
```

Successfully loaded from txt via gremlin using cassandra backend ([How to import a CSV file into Titan graph database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19006616/how-to-import-a-csv-file-into-titan-graph-database)). But still need to do it from my app. I changed; 
config.setProperty("storage.backend", "inmemory"); 
to 
config.setProperty("storage.backend", "cassandra");

but when opening connection (graph = TitanFactory.open(config);) getting this error;

```
18:26:15.503 [main] DEBUG c.t.t.d.c.a.AstyanaxStoreManager - About to instantiate class public com.netflix.astyanax.connectionpool.impl.FixedRetryBackoffStrategy(int,int) with 2 arguments
18:26:15.509 [main] DEBUG c.t.t.d.c.a.AstyanaxStoreManager - Instantiated RetryBackoffStrategy object com.netflix.astyanax.connectionpool.impl.FixedRetryBackoffStrategy@52e6fdee from config string "com.netflix.astyanax.connectionpool.impl.FixedRetryBackoffStrategy,1000,5000"
18:26:15.511 [main] DEBUG c.t.t.d.c.a.AstyanaxStoreManager - About to instantiate class public com.netflix.astyanax.retry.BoundedExponentialBackoff(long,long,int) with 3 arguments
18:26:15.512 [main] DEBUG c.t.t.d.c.a.AstyanaxStoreManager - Instantiated RetryPolicy object com.netflix.astyanax.retry.BoundedExponentialBackoff@7ec7ffd3[maxSleepTimeMs=25000,MAX_SHIFT=30,random=java.util.Random@dd8ba08,baseSleepTimeMs=100,maxAttempts=8,attempts=0] from config string "com.netflix.astyanax.retry.BoundedExponentialBackoff,100,25000,8"
18:26:15.530 [main] DEBUG c.t.t.d.c.a.AstyanaxStoreManager - Custom RetryBackoffStrategy com.netflix.astyanax.connectionpool.impl.FixedRetryBackoffStrategy@52e6fdee
18:26:15.810 [main] INFO  c.n.a.c.i.ConnectionPoolMBeanManager - Registering mbean: com.netflix.MonitoredResources:type=ASTYANAX,name=ClusterTitanConnectionPool,ServiceType=connectionpool
18:26:15.823 [main] INFO  c.n.a.c.i.CountingConnectionPoolMonitor - AddHost: 192.168.200.141
18:26:16.851 [pool-4-thread-1] DEBUG c.n.astyanax.thrift.ThriftConverter - java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
18:26:25.832 [main] DEBUG c.t.t.d.c.a.AstyanaxStoreManager - Failed to describe keyspace titan
18:26:25.832 [main] DEBUG c.t.t.d.c.a.AstyanaxStoreManager - Creating keyspace titan...
18:26:26.853 [pool-4-thread-1] DEBUG c.n.astyanax.thrift.ThriftConverter - java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
18:26:35.848 [main] DEBUG c.t.t.d.c.a.AstyanaxStoreManager - Failed to create keyspace titan
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not instantiate implementation: com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.cassandra.astyanax.AstyanaxStoreManager
at com.thinkaurelius.titan.util.system.ConfigurationUtil.instantiate(ConfigurationUtil.java:55)
at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.Backend.getImplementationClass(Backend.java:421)
at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.Backend.getStorageManager(Backend.java:361)
at com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.configuration.GraphDatabaseConfiguration.<init>(GraphDatabaseConfiguration.java:1275)
at com.thinkaurelius.titan.core.TitanFactory.open(TitanFactory.java:93)
at com.thinkaurelius.titan.core.TitanFactory.open(TitanFactory.java:73)
at tr.com.kale.titanbulk.TitanBulk$5.widgetSelected(TitanBulk.java:196)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Unknown Source)
at tr.com.kale.titanbulk.TitanBulk.open(TitanBulk.java:68)
at tr.com.kale.titanbulk.TitanBulk.main(TitanBulk.java:52)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at com.thinkaurelius.titan.util.system.ConfigurationUtil.instantiate(ConfigurationUtil.java:44)
... 13 more
Caused by: com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.TemporaryBackendException: Temporary failure in storage backend
at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.cassandra.astyanax.AstyanaxStoreManager.ensureKeyspaceExists(AstyanaxStoreManager.java:563)
at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.cassandra.astyanax.AstyanaxStoreManager.<init>(AstyanaxStoreManager.java:283)
... 18 more
Caused by: com.netflix.astyanax.connectionpool.exceptions.PoolTimeoutException: PoolTimeoutException: [host=192.168.200.141(192.168.200.141):9160, latency=10002(10002), attempts=1]Timed out waiting for connection
at com.netflix.astyanax.connectionpool.impl.SimpleHostConnectionPool.waitForConnection(SimpleHostConnectionPool.java:231)
at com.netflix.astyanax.connectionpool.impl.SimpleHostConnectionPool.borrowConnection(SimpleHostConnectionPool.java:198)
at com.netflix.astyanax.connectionpool.impl.RoundRobinExecuteWithFailover.borrowConnection(RoundRobinExecuteWithFailover.java:84)
at com.netflix.astyanax.connectionpool.impl.AbstractExecuteWithFailoverImpl.tryOperation(AbstractExecuteWithFailoverImpl.java:117)
at com.netflix.astyanax.connectionpool.impl.AbstractHostPartitionConnectionPool.executeWithFailover(AbstractHostPartitionConnectionPool.java:338)
at com.netflix.astyanax.thrift.ThriftClusterImpl.executeSchemaChangeOperation(ThriftClusterImpl.java:146)
at com.netflix.astyanax.thrift.ThriftClusterImpl.internalCreateKeyspace(ThriftClusterImpl.java:321)
at com.netflix.astyanax.thrift.ThriftClusterImpl.addKeyspace(ThriftClusterImpl.java:294)
at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.cassandra.astyanax.AstyanaxStoreManager.ensureKeyspaceExists(AstyanaxStoreManager.java:558)
... 19 more
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Graph may not be null
at com.tinkerpop.blueprints.util.wrappers.batch.BatchGraph.<init>(BatchGraph.java:81)
at tr.com.kale.titanbulk.TitanBulk$5.widgetSelected(TitanBulk.java:206)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Unknown Source)
at tr.com.kale.titanbulk.TitanBulk.open(TitanBulk.java:68)
at tr.com.kale.titanbulk.TitanBulk.main(TitanBulk.java:52)
```

I also tried cassandrathrift;

```
18:35:18.296 [main] DEBUG c.t.t.d.c.t.t.CTConnectionFactory - Creating TSocket(192.168.200.141, 9160, null, null, 10000)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not instantiate implementation: com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.cassandra.thrift.CassandraThriftStoreManager
at com.thinkaurelius.titan.util.system.ConfigurationUtil.instantiate(ConfigurationUtil.java:55)
at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.Backend.getImplementationClass(Backend.java:421)
at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.Backend.getStorageManager(Backend.java:361)
at com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.configuration.GraphDatabaseConfiguration.<init>(GraphDatabaseConfiguration.java:1275)
at com.thinkaurelius.titan.core.TitanFactory.open(TitanFactory.java:93)
at com.thinkaurelius.titan.core.TitanFactory.open(TitanFactory.java:73)
at tr.com.kale.titanbulk.TitanBulk$5.widgetSelected(TitanBulk.java:196)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Unknown Source)
at tr.com.kale.titanbulk.TitanBulk.open(TitanBulk.java:68)
at tr.com.kale.titanbulk.TitanBulk.main(TitanBulk.java:52)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at com.thinkaurelius.titan.util.system.ConfigurationUtil.instantiate(ConfigurationUtil.java:44)
... 13 more
Caused by: com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.TemporaryBackendException: Temporary failure in storage backend
at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.cassandra.thrift.CassandraThriftStoreManager.getCassandraPartitioner(CassandraThriftStoreManager.java:218)
at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.cassandra.thrift.CassandraThriftStoreManager.<init>(CassandraThriftStoreManager.java:196)
... 18 more
Caused by: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSocket.open(TSocket.java:187)
at org.apache.thrift.transport.TFramedTransport.open(TFramedTransport.java:81)
at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.cassandra.thrift.thriftpool.CTConnectionFactory.makeRawConnection(CTConnectionFactory.java:88)
at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.cassandra.thrift.thriftpool.CTConnectionFactory.makeObject(CTConnectionFactory.java:52)
at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.cassandra.thrift.thriftpool.CTConnectionFactory.makeObject(CTConnectionFactory.java:21)
at org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericKeyedObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericKeyedObjectPool.java:1220)
at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.cassandra.thrift.CassandraThriftStoreManager.getCassandraPartitioner(CassandraThriftStoreManager.java:215)
... 19 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSocket.open(TSocket.java:182)
... 25 more
```

Thanks.

Comment: Could you clarify where your problem is exactly?  It seems like you've had problems and solved some on your own but I can't tell exactly where you are stuck aside from perhaps connecting to cassandra.  Is that the main issue?  If so, it seems that you should check your network connectivity to your cassandra instance - double check that ports are open.  Perhaps test on localhost first to just validate that you can get a connection.

Comment: I'm happy to see you here. I viewed all of questions and answers about titan last week. Common point of them, your answers. First, i tried "inmemory" backend, after i created property keys via gremlin, but get error "Property Key with given name does not exist". I realized, its just memory not storage. I think, property keys must be define in same transaction while using inmemory backend. Then changed backend to "cassandra" to write data to storage, but i get connection error messages like "Connection refused: connect".

Comment: I commented port definition on BaseConfiguration properties in mycode but same error. After that i tried gremlin interface on localhost to load my file with cassandra backend and successfuly loaded. So main problem is connecting to cassandra backend from my client app. I think if i connect to cassandra my code will work fine.

Comment: Yes - this doesn't sound like a Titan problem.  If your code works properly on localhost then your issue is merely with your network, cassandra configuration or the like.  Get a basic connection working to your remote cluster and your problems should get solved.

Comment: I examined firewall logs, there is no any deny. Also examined all of property, xml and yaml files in server but no any clue. I couldn't open connection from my pc to titan server :(

Answer (score 0):

I can find a few error here.

First of all you cannot use "id" as property key name cause it's a reserved word.

Secondly for you should have created a propertyKey for each property you would like to add using the management api `mng.makePropertyKey("prop").dataType(String.class).make();` for example.

here's a test with batch loading that works

```
    @Test
    public void bulkLoad(){
    BaseConfiguration config = new BaseConfiguration();
    config.setProperty("storage.backend", "inmemory");
    config.setProperty("storage.batch-loading", "true");
    TitanGraph graph = TitanFactory.open(config);
    TitanManagement mng = graph.getManagementSystem();
    if (mng.getPropertyKey("prop") == null) {
        PropertyKey pk = mng.makePropertyKey("prop").dataType(String.class).make();
        mng.buildIndex("prop_index", Vertex.class).addKey(pk).buildCompositeIndex();
    }
    mng.commit();

    BatchGraph bg = new BatchGraph(graph, VertexIDType.STRING, 1000);
    System.out.println("Start bulk loading");
    IntStream.range(1,1000).forEach(i -> {
        Vertex v = bg.addVertex("id"+i);
        v.setProperty("prop", "prop"+i);
    });
    bg.commit();

    assertNotNull(bg.getVertex("id10"));
    assertEquals("prop10",bg.getVertex("id10").getProperty("prop"));
}
```